# having trouble uploading video to telegram with aiogram lib

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiogram

was writing a bot that goes through several tokens and sends a video

error i encountered:

> aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

code:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from io import BytesIO
import requests


tokens = ['6766800741:AAHq3w*****************************',
          '6759714409:AAFabo*****************************',
          '6822677705:AAFylR*****************************']
dp = Dispatcher()


async def popa():
    resp = requests.get('https://cdn77-vid-mp4.xvideos-cdn.com/tWE5jUC1yt64rY5u3i-WcA==,1704260661/videos/3gp/e/6/c/xvideos.com_e6c4845505f215a6fc52c97645444d97.mp4?ui=MTA5LjI1Mi43Mi4xMTgtL3ZpZGVvNzQzMTEwMDkvdGdpcmxzLnh4eF9zaGVf')
    vid = BytesIO(resp.content)
    types.BufferedInputFile(vid.read(), 'ytgbyuivtby.mp4')
    await bot.send_video('-100*******747', 'ytgbyuivtby.mp4')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t in tokens:
        bot = Bot(t)
        asyncio.run(popa())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.